# (SQL query) Set value for no data in same column compare to another row

Tags: sql, ms-access

Kindly give help,

I try to make query for Ms.Access with odbc connection from PHP page.

I have this tabel(**table1**)

```
class   quantity    date 
1   30  01/04/2014 
2   23  01/04/2014 
3   23  01/04/2014 
4   14  01/04/2014 
5   5   01/04/2014 
1   41  01/05/2014 
2   38  01/05/2014 
3   36  01/05/2014 
4   28  01/05/2014 
5   25  01/05/2014 
6   1   01/05/2014
```

Kindly give help for query to get this output :

```
class   quantity    date 
1   30  01/04/2014 
2   23  01/04/2014 
3   23  01/04/2014 
4   14  01/04/2014 
5   5   01/04/2014 
6   0   0 
1   41  01/05/2014 
2   38  01/05/2014 
3   36  01/05/2014 
4   28  01/05/2014 
5   25  01/05/2014 
6   1   01/05/2014
```

In the output will show 0 as quantity for class 6 who actually no record for class 6 in 01/04/2014.

Comment: Is this actually a table or is it a query? How do you know to have 6 and not 7 or 8 classes?

Comment: Above is a table in Microsoft Access,

commonly I have 1 to 6 class in my database, and no record with class 6 for month 4 (April).
In output I need all class throwing value min 0 value in each class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `union all`.  But a more general solution is this:

```
select c.class, d.date, nz(t1.quantity, 0)
from ((select distinct class from table1) as c cross join
      (select distinct date from table1) as d
     ) left join
     table1 as t1
     on t1.class = c.class and t1.date = d.date
```

Comment: Thanks, <br />
but I stil got this error : odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in JOIN operation